# Joomla 3 Show Title issue. Hide page-header

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I turned Show Title option for articles to Hide in global settings. So it works for each my page good instead of home page. So the title is still appear, even if I switched it to hide in article that correspond to Home page content.

I suppose maybe something wrong with menu.

So I have next menu:

- Home
- Photos
- Contacts

Each menu content single article, but only Home shows title...

I am using joomla 3

on the screenshot below Home header that I don't need.

[image]

on the screenshot below Videos header that set as Show tile in menu item
[image]

on the screenshot below Videos header that set as Hide tile in menu item
[image]

I am making the same for Home but it does not work the Home tile is still visible.

I tapped on menu items then on home items which is single article:

[image]

then I modify visibility options:

[image]

save and close - and then update the index page in browser, but nothing happen the header Home is still on the page (

Answer (score 16):

The solution is next:

1. Click on the “Menus” menu and select “Main Menu”.
2. Click on the menu item that represents your home page (usually “Home” or something similar)
3. On the right side, click on “Page Display Options”
4. Set “Show Page Heading” to “No”
5. Click on “Save”

http://www.celticwolf.com/blog/2012/09/06/how-to-hide-the-page-heading-in-joomla-2-5/

Comment: Page Display Options does not exist on the right in Joomla 3.0! New posted so it would not let me add images for you to see that Page Display Opotion does not exist.

Comment: "Page Display" is in the menu item's horizontal top menu in Joomla 3.3

Comment: This should be the solution. Had the same issue today, you have to disable the home page heading in the display options in the menu item.

Answer (score 2):

You have an option to `show` or `hide` the title of `Articles` and also `Menus`. Usualy is "Home" also the dafault `"Frontpage"` of the site, having the option to show the title.

Go to Menus -> Default "Home" Menu and under options you should have `Show Title` and hide it.

This should work, i tested it right now on my page to be sure.

Regards

Comment: Sorry can you explain more detail?

Comment: Here are 3 steps. The green horizontal line indicates it is another 'page', when you are mooving trough the admin panel.

It is hard to explain better where do you disable showing the title. Or is it something else you want explained? Link: http://shrani.si/f/3x/bQ/29R5gVdI/untitled.png

Comment: I have checked class it is = entry-title page-header

I hide the same as in your example, but there is still header

Comment: Could you give me the link to your page, if its accessable from internet. If not, make a screenshot and describe what exactly do you want to be gone there.

Comment: Could you please give me the link to the template you are using so i can re-animate the problem on my server?

Comment: Unfortunaley it is local one

Comment: If the template you have is your OWN product(not a free template you downloaded from web), then you should know where you have put the main title. I just installed a fresh joomla site and i installed the testing sample data. I went to the main menu and disabled showing the title and it was gone. Is there no way i could get your template to my machine?

Comment: you can download it here (use dankotemplate) https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4w6fi9tig6s2w7/Joomla_3.zip

Comment: I would also need a exported MYSQL database you are using, to make it work.

Comment: I have added it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2eek5h68wr4o22/databaseintxt.rtf

Comment: I cannot import that database to my mysql server, i get too many errors. Is there no way i could access your webpage from public?

Comment: sorry still have not got public (

Comment: I would defenitly know where to search for the code and remove it, but i cannot install the template on my server...it is impossible for me, to tell you what everything you could try to achieve your result.. I am Sorry. But mainly, my above solution will work for any template you install. Except for custom templates people write on their own and down implement them good with joomla, so you cant edit them trough the admin panel options.

Regards

Comment: really thank you for help, i will try it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: I have question here? Go to Menus -> Default "Home" Menu and under options you should have Show Title. I don't have Show Title when I click in menus then Main Menu then Options. I just see Menus Manager with 3 settings but without show title

Comment: I have found the answer here http://www.celticwolf.com/blog/2012/09/06/how-to-hide-the-page-heading-in-joomla-2-5/

Comment: I suppose you written about the same thing but for another version. am I right?

Answer (score 2):

in joomla 3.x it will be possible by combination of backend settings and source code change.

1. Login to your joomla control panel.
2. Go to Global\Articles and turn the "Show Title" and "Article info Title" to Hide.
3. Go to Global\Menus and turn the "Show Page Heading" to Hide.
4. Login to your host and go to your public html directory then go to "\templates**[your template]**\html\com_content\article" directory.
5. open `default.php` in editor and find
   `php if $this->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)` :
   and change the `1` to `0` then save it.

I suggest you to backup `default.php` file before any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Page Heading in the Menu Item options as showed below in my screenshot:

[image]

if this don't work, try to go to MENUS - MANAGE - (press the button OPTIONS to the right of the page)

In browser page title press one space , the set the second voice to NO:

[image]

Then save and press the REBUILD button.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have a multi language site. The "Show Page Heading" option inside the languages home menu doesn´t works at all in this case. It is overrided by the Main Menu home options (that one without any languages assigned to it, that is mandatory in Joomla).

So if you change the "Show Page Heading" option inside the Main Menu home options, it will work.

Bizarre. But, it´s the way that Joomla 3 works.